# Функция не видит массив. Почему?

Tags: python, telebot

```
File "E:\telebot\new_bot.py", line 53, in button_menu 
design_items(message)
File "E:\telebot\new_bot.py", line 75, in design_items
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(r'des_img','rb'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'des_img'
```

My code:

```
items = ['E:\telebot\img\samples\1.jpg',
 'E:\telebot\img\samples\2.jpg',
]

def design_items(message):
for des_img in items:
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(r'des_img','rb'))
```

Глаза уже стёрлись читать... не понимаю. Памагите кто может. Кто может, памагите...

Comment: Ну так уберите кавычки, des_img - это же название переменной, его надо без кавычек передавать )

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно брать название переменной в кавычки, у вас из-за этого вместо значения переменной получается строка с именем переменной:

```
    for des_img in items:
        ^^^^^^^ переменная цикла
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(des_img,'rb'))
                                                   ^^^^^^^ её использование
```